# CS1061: 'Page' does not contain a definition for 'cBannerImage' Error in mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a form view where I get the page content name and picture

But i got this error:

"CS1061: 'Page' does not contain a definition for 'cBannerImage' and no accessible extension method 'cBannerImage' accepting a first argument of type 'Page' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

why am i getting this error and how can i fix it?

**Page Model :**

```
namespace ArilWebYonetimPaneli.Models
{
    public class Page
    {
        public int? iPageId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Dil")]
        public int? iLanguageId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Kuşak Resmi")]
        public string cBannerImage { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Sayfa Başlığı")]
        public string cTitle { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Sayfa içeriği")]
        [AllowHtml]
        public string cContent { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Aktif")]
        public int iIsActive { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Aktif")]
        public int iActive { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Pasif")]
        public int iPasive { get; set; }
        public DateTime dUpdateDate { get; set; }

        public string cUpdateDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime dInsertDate { get; set; }


    }
}
```

**PageController:**

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddUpdate(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Session["iUserId"] == null && GetCookie("iUserId") == null)
            {
                return Redirect("/AdminUsers/Login");
            }

            int iUserLogin = 0;
            if (Session["iUserId"] != null && Convert.ToInt32(Session["iUserId"]) > 0)
            {
                iUserLogin = Convert.ToInt32(Session["iUserId"]);
            }
            else if (GetCookie("iUserId") != null && Convert.ToInt32(GetCookie("iUserId")) > 0)
            {
                iUserLogin = Convert.ToInt32(GetCookie("iUserId"));
            }

            ViewBag.LanguagesList = new Models.Languages().Send();

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {
                int iPageId = 0;
                if (int.TryParse(id, out iPageId) && iPageId > 0)
                {
                    using (Data.DataClassesDataContext dc = new Data.DataClassesDataContext())
                    {
                        var read = (from table in dc.Pages
                                    where
                                      table.iPageId == iPageId &&
                                      (table.iActive == 0 || table.iActive == 1)
                                    select new Models.Page
                                    {
                                        iPageId = table.iPageId,
                                        iLanguageId = (int)table.iLanguageId,
                                        cBannerImage = table.cBannerImage,
                                        cTitle = table.cTitle,
                                        cContent = table.cContent,
                                        iIsActive = (int)table.iActive,
                                        dUpdateDate = (table.dUpdateDate != null ? Convert.ToDateTime(table.dUpdateDate) : Convert.ToDateTime("1900-01-01")),
                                        cUpdateDate = String.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm}", (table.dUpdateDate != null ? Convert.ToDateTime(table.dUpdateDate) : Convert.ToDateTime("1900-01-01"))),
                                    }).FirstOrDefault();
                        return View(read);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.iSonuc = -2;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            ViewBag.iSonuc = -2;
        }

        return View();
    }
```

And AddUpdate View:

```
@model ArilWebYonetimPaneli.Models.Page
@section Styles{
    @*JQUERY UI*@
    <link href="~/assets/global/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @*SELECT2*@
    <link href="../assets/global/plugins/select2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../assets/global/plugins/select2/css/select2-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="~/ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script>
}
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddUpdate";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div class="content">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddUpdate", "Page", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <div class="form-body">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.iPageId)

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.iLanguageId)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.iLanguageId, new SelectList(ViewBag.LanguagesList, "iLanguagesId", "cLanguagesName"), "Lütfen dil seçin ...", new { @class = "form-control", @tabindex = 1 })
            </div>

            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.cBannerImage)
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cBannerImage)

            <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput2" id="fileinput2">
                @if (Model != null && Model.iPageId > 0 && Model.iPageId != null)
                {
                    <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                        <img src="/Images/@Model.cBannerImage" id="imgId" alt="" />
                    </div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no+image" alt="" />
                    </div>
                }
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <span class="btn default btn-file">
                            <input type="file" name="file" id="file2">
                        </span>
                        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="DeleteImage(this)" class="btn default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"> Remove </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cTitle)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.cTitle, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Lütfen sayfa başlığı giriniz..." })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group last">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cContent)
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.cContent, new { @class = "ckeditor form-control", placeholder = "Lütfen içerik giriniz...", @name = "editor1", @rows = "10" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="mt-radio-inline">
                    <label class="mt-radio">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.iIsActive, 1, new { @name = "optionsRadios", @id = "iActive", @value = "option1", @checked = "checked" }) Aktif
                        <span></span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="mt-radio">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.iIsActive, 0, new { @name = "optionsRadios", @id = "iPasive", @value = "option1" }) Pasif
                        <span></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            @{ Html.RenderPartial("/Views/Partials/WarningMessages.cshtml"); }

        </div>
        <hr />
        if (Model != null && Model.iPageId > 0)
        {
            <div class="form-actions right"><button type="submit" class="btn green">Güncelle</button></div>
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="form-actions right"><button type="submit" class="btn green">Ekle</button></div>
        }

    }
</div>
@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/MjrScripts/upload.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'];
    if (editor) { editor.destroy(true); }
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
        enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
    });
    CKFinder.setupCKEditor(null, '@Url.Content("~/ckfinder/")');
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#iUrl").select2();
            $("#iLanguageId").select2();
        });
    </script>

}
```

Comment: Which line in the code throws the error?

Comment: @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.cBannerImage) this line in view

Comment: Any exceptions threw when using `@Model.cBannerImage` in the view file?

Comment: No it's okey but i when run i got this error

Comment: `Page` is a not uncommon name used in asp.net. It's possible that you're picking up the *wrong* `Page` class. I'd suggest picking a different name for your class.